# flask session error with issues in cli.py __init__.py etc

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I am using importing flask sessions and on using flask run in environment mode I'am having the following error:

> Error: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\adnan\desktop\technology\cs50 web  programming\src2\routes0\env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
>       **import**(module_name)
>         File "C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\Technology\CS50 Web Programming\src2\Flask_Practice\notes\application.py", line 7, in 
>       Session(app)
>         File "c:\users\adnan\desktop\technology\cs50 web programming\src2\routes0\env\lib\site-packages\flask_session__init__.py", line 54, in **init**
>       self.init_app(app)
>         File "c:\users\adnan\desktop\technology\cs50 web programming\src2\routes0\env\lib\site-packages\flask_session__init__.py", line 61, in init_app
>       app.session_interface = self._get_interface(app)
>         File "c:\users\adnan\desktop\technology\cs50 web programming\src2\routes0\env\lib\site-packages\flask_session__init__.py", line 90, in _get_interface
>       session_interface = FileSystemSessionInterface(
>         File "c:\users\adnan\desktop\technology\cs50 web programming\src2\routes0\env\lib\site-packages\flask_session\sessions.py", line 313, in **init**
>       from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'

Here is my main code in python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

notes = []

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        notes.append(note)

    return render_template("index.html", notes=notes)
```

Comment: Try installing werkzeug. `pip intall werkzeug`.

Comment: already installed but it didn't worked

Comment: Can you share the version number of the `werkzeug` module.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall werkzeug, from 1.0.0 to 0.16.0
Working
pip install werkzeug==0.16.0